# Identity datetime? field doesn't allow null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've extended `IdentityUser` with a `ApplicationUser` class with several custom fields to match the `AspNetUsers` table I have in a SQL Server DB. A couple of them are defined in SQL as, for example: `MyDate datetime2 null`. In my `ApplicationUser` class it would be: `datetime? MyDate;`.

Now, the only way I can set it to null is with a T-SQL command separate from Entity Framework and if it is null, my application throws an exception reading it from the DB.

I do admit that it was erroneously declared as `datetime MyDate` in `ApplicationUser` for awhile before I updated it to match the DB. Is this the cause of the problems I'm seeing? If so, how do I get my `ApplicationUser` to match the current DB schema?

Here's the exception:

```
01/10/19 17:14:47.034 ERROR 114 MyApp.Global - Exception occurred: 
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Data.ConstraintException: The 'MyDateUtc' property on 'ApplicationUser' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'. 
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Here's the `ApplicationUser` class (trimmed a bit) and supporting classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override long Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? MyDateUtc { get; set; }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(UserManager<ApplicationUser, long> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyDbConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<long, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, long, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, long, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the exception that you're getting when you read the data.  Did you run an applicable migration (if using code first) that changed your field from nullable to non-nullable?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've added the exception. I didn't run any kind of migration and am unfamiliar with that. I updated the table in SQL Server and edited the ApplicationUser class to match.

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netfra) is a `Struct` and as such, is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types). This means it the cannot be set to `null`.

You may solve your problem with the help of the nullable operator. 
Using a question mark (?) after the type or using the generic style [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

```
Nullable <DateTime> MyDateUtc;
```

or

```
DateTime? MyDateUtc;
```

You should check your `DbContext` class just in case your class' property is being set as required. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional)

Comment: I am declaring it as `datetime? MyDate`. That's my issue, as it's not being treated that way. As mentioned in the question, I mistakenly declared it as `datetime MyDate` but updated it.

Comment: And you get the exact same exception after changing that?

Comment: Which EF version are you using?

Comment: I'm using EF 6.2.0, and Identity 2.2.2. Yes, I'm getting the error, that's the whole point of my question.

Comment: Ok then. Check the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext class. Look for the ApplicationUser entity and see if the conflicting property is set to required by the modelbuilder.

Comment: If there hasn't been an ef-migration run to add/update this field, then EF probably still thinks that the property is non-nullable.

Comment: Any pointers on how to do that? With a quick survey it mentions recreating the database. I absolutely do not want to do that. I just want Identity to use what is currently in the DB.

Comment: Can you share the definition of ApplicationUser and DbContext?

Comment: Check this out: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37797.asp-net-identity-customize-user-authentication.aspx

Comment: One other thing you should be aware of is, if you created an [EDMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first#5-dealing-with-database-changes) file then open it with the graphical editor. You should see AppicationUser table, click on MyDateUtc and it should display all its properties in the Property Tool Window. Check the Nullable property, it should be ser to true.

Comment: There is no EDMX file, I've looked for it. I'm not sure I care for all these hooks being shoved into my database. believe I understand why they are there but I don't like it. Thanks Emilio and Brendan for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I have trouble accepting this answer, since any resolution is in the comments and are different from it. Something more explicit would be better. Thanks again!

Comment: Emilio, I  haven't yet but I feel from your and Brendan's comments I will be able to as it seems the model just needs to be regenerated to match the DB. I'll be away for the next couple days so won't know for sure until later. Again, thanks.